# parsing string with keyword = contend using both single or double delimiting quotes

Tags: php, parsing, double-quotes

find  many

> keyword="text with quotes "
>
> but none ignoring  double or single quotes     keyword="text with
>   quotes " or keyword='text with quotes'
>
> i produced following code  but it does not work
>
> > function GENERIC_FIND_KEYWORD_AND_QUOTED_TEXT($STR)
> >     {  // keyword=" "    surrounded by  whitespace or non symbol strings (outside off   a-zA-Z0-9_
>
> // using  (key1=' embeded qwuotes' AND key2=" embeded  qwuotes") !key3=' embeded qwuotes' key4=" embeded qwuotes" ...  // as input string
>
> ```
>    $res=preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}=("((?:[^\\\]*?(?:\\\")?)*?)"|\'((?:[^\\\]*?(?:\\\')?)*?)\')/', $str, $arr, PREG_SET_ORDER);
> ```
>
> print_r($arr);echo "";   // would
>
> like    an array  like     array('key1'=>'text','key2'=>"text"
>   ,'key3'=>'text','key4'=>'text','key5'=>'text')  }
>
> It does not work but is suppoed  to match multiple times per line  on
>       a symbol (defined as [a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}
>      endded with  =     a single or double quote 
>      the quoted string  should be detected  ignoring  quoted quotes  inbetween the 
>   single or doubled quotes....

the keyword is not surrounded by whitespace as in XML but with any non symbol characters or whitespace.....
ex I want to verify  all mysql keywords  and matching  constructs ...

where  the  ? makes it a keyword of special interest

input output   structure:

input: little or no control, I do not have an idea what the user is going to enter 
the idea is to be s generic as possible especially ; considering all in the quoted strings

> keyword="bla 'bla  "" dfddfd"     or  keword2='dfdfd " dsdsdfsdfdf'

sure it must be stated correctly and consistently ....

> output:        array   (  keyword =>"bla 'bla  "" dfddfd",
>                             keyword2=>'dfdfd " dsdsdfsdfdf',
>                             ...)

secondly:(slightly different related problem)
I would like  to filter  special tagged  keywords  to replace them later(need unchanged components)

> keyword="bla 'bla  "" dfddfd"     or/and   _keword2='dfdfd " dsdsdfsdfdf'

where I only get  the  taged components  _*="...."   filtered (suppose it is  more efficient  changing the match patern  then  loop through all array elements  to find the secondary keyword patern...
\

> output:        array   (  _keyword2=>'dfdfd " dsdsdfsdfdf',
>                             ...)

Comment: Can you give us a full input example (hopefully one that you have difficultly with) and then the full ideal result data structure (`$arr`?) of what the input would create?

Answer (score 0):

RegEx:

```
/([^ ]+)\=((\"([^"]+)\")|(\'([^']+)\'))/
```